# How to edit a date field in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, field, datetime

So I want to edit date type filed on entry save, but I don't know how to format it. It times out on string and don't seem to accept DateTime objects either.

```
Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(ElementEvent $event) {
        if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\Entry) {
            $entry = $event->element;
            if($entry->sectionId == 16){
                $entry->rangeStart = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', '01/01/2019:19:00:00');
                Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is you are calling saveElement from EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT which is causing an infinite loop.

You need to set:

```
$entry->propagating = true;
```

Before calling the saveElement method.

Dates should be a PHP DateTime class, e.g:

```
$entry->rangeStart = new \DateTime('2019-04-10 19:00:00');
```

Comment: Ahh I was so set on date that I didn't see the loop, however setting $entry->propagating = true; didn't help. I've switched to before save event instead and now it works.